# uIP DNS clinet fails if external DNS server is used

Tags: networking, embedded, cortex-m, contiki, lpc

I've using the uIP stack to send HTTP posts to a remote webserver with some sensor data. I'm using resolv.c (included as part of uIP) as the DNS client to resolve the remote webserver domain name to IP address. All works well as long as I use the router (192.168.1.1) as the DNS server address. But if I try to use any external DNS server address (such as Google's public DNS server 8.8.8.8), then it fails to resolve. The router firewall is ruled out as I've tried using same external DNS servers on computers whose network settings are manually configured and it works just fine. I'm struck at this problems since a long time and would be grateful if someone can help me solve this problem!

My platform uses the RDB1768 (based on LPC1768) + LPCxpresso. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Does your router allow you to access the external recource if you open it by it's ip-address from the device? I mean, can you do it if you don't use DNS client?

Comment: Run a packet sniffer to see what's going on.